# Prevent Ajax refresh of URL parameters

Tags: jsf, primefaces, prettyfaces

I am using `prettyfaces-3.4.2` with `primefaces-7.0` and I wanted to use a bean property in my URL as the documentation show it.

*pretty-config.xml*

```
<url-mapping id="myUrl1">
    <pattern value="/#{myBean.param}" />
    <view-id value="/views/myView.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

*MyBean.java*

```
@Named(value = "myBean")
@ViewScoped
public class myBean implements Serializable {
    private String param;
    private String str1;
    private String str2;

    public void loadStr1() {
        if (param.equals("new")) this.str1 = "new_value";
        else this.str1 = "default_value";
    }        

    // getters & setters

    public void setParam() {
        this.param = param;
        loadStr1();
    }
}
```

*myView.xhtml*

```
<h:form>
    <p:inputText value="#{myBean.str1}">
        <p:ajax />
    </p:inputText>

    <p:inputText value="#{myBean.str2}">
        <p:ajax />
    </p:inputText>
</h:form>
```

My problem is that each time I change the value of my inputs which trigger a new ajax request to update my bean properties (`str1` & `str2`), it triggers again the setter of my url parameter (`param`) because a new request is executed.

So, it triggers my `loadStr1` each time an ajax request is made, resetting my `str1` value.

Is it the normal behavior that ajax requests call setter of url parameter ? And can I prevent it ?

Comment: You have another problem in your code: https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832

Comment: @BalusC just made a mistake building a simple similar example of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PrettyFaces `onPostBack` parameter of `<action>` seems to do the job.

```xml
<url-mapping id="myUrl1">
    <pattern value="/#{myBean.param}" />
    <view-id value="/views/myView.xhtml" />
    <action onPostback="false">#{myBean.loadStr1}</action>
</url-mapping>
```

And then I just remove the call of `loadStr1` from `MyBean`.

```java
public void setParam() {
    this.param = param;
    /*loadStr1();*/
}
```